# Heatpipe in Motor shaft

Tags: electric-vehicle, tesla

I stumbled across this [Tesla Patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140368064A1/en) for a Heatpipe in the electric motor's rotor shaft in order to get the Heat out of the Rotor.

Does anyone know if Tesla is actually using this Technology in one of their cars, or do the just hold the Patent? If the latter is true, why are they not using it? (E.g. cost, does not really work, efficiency)?

Comment: Amusingly, it omits the one design feature that makes a rotating heat pipe work effectively. But hey, Musk didn't get where he is today by obeying the laws of physics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this design was never used in production vehicles. The patent application dates from 2013, and the grant from 2016. I'd guess it was a design alternative to the new motors introduced with the 2017 Model 3 RWD, and wasn't used because it didn't work out as well, or cost too much to produce.

That said we could still see this, or some variation on it, show up in some future vehicle.

Comment: There are companies selling heat pipes for rotating machinery that do work (at speeds up to 10,000 RPM). The patent makes the schoolboy error (at least to anybody who works with rotating machinery) of ignoring how the fluid flow in the pipe will be affected by the rotation!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!
@alephzero: can you give me a hint what the general problem with rotating heat pipes is about and who these companies are?